# C++ CLR Managed DLL containing template classes to be used in C#

Tags: c#, .net, templates, dll, c++-cli

Here is the one of the template class inside my dll:

```
template <class Type>
public ref class linkedList {
protected:
    nodeType<Type>^ head;
    nodeType<Type>^ tail;

public:
    linkedList();
    linkedList(const nodeType<Type>^newHead);

    nodeType<Type>^ getHead() { return head; }
    nodeType<Type>^ getTail() { return tail; }
    void push(const Type item);
    Type pop();

    bool isEmpty();

    void refreshTail();
    void print();
    void destroy();
    void appendToTail(nodeType<Type>^const newNode);
    ~linkedList();
};
```

This is already defined. However, when I reference the dll, its namespace does not show.
I tried to add a non-template class like this:

```
    public ref class number{
private: int x;
public: void exFunction(int y){ x=y;}
};
```

and then the namespace appears. Lets say the namespace is "MP", I use "using MP;" in c#.
By having that, I was able to call the exFunction but not the other classes which are template classes. How can I call the template classes?

Comment: Exact same restriction as in native C++, templates don't have external linkage so much be declared in a .h file.  Which is a **very** bad idea for a class you declare *public*, you'll get very hard to diagnose InvalidCastExceptions at runtime.  And completely unusable to C# code.  Do avoid reinventing the wheel and use System::Collections::Generic::LinkedList instead.  A *generic* class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your C++/CLI dll, use 'generic' instead:

```
generic<class Type>
public ref class linkedList
```

Some clarification on this: C++/CLI allows both 'template' and 'generic' - 'template' works like the typical native C++ template, while 'generic' works like generics in C#.